# pandas join on index of a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have three lists which look like this:

```
l1 = ["a", "b" , "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

l2 = ["a", "d", "f"]

l3 = ["b", "g"]
```

I would like to get a dataframe which looks like this:

```
| l1 | l2   | l3   |
|----|------|------|
| a  | a    | None |
| b  | None | b    |
| c  | None | None |
| d  | d    | None |
| e  | None | None |
| f  | f    | None |
| g  | None | g    |
```

I have tried to use the `join`/`merge` operations but could not figure this out.

How could i accomplish this?

Comment: Only 3 lists? You can use `pd.DataFrame(l1, index=l1, columns=['l1']).assign(l2=pd.Series(l2, index=l2), l3=pd.Series(l3, index=l3))` but this seems a bit to localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using list comprehensions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = [i if i in l2 else np.nan for i in l1]
b = [i if i in l3 else np.nan for i in l1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'l1': l1, 'l2': a, 'l3': b})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  l1   l2   l3
0  a    a  NaN
1  b  NaN    b
2  c  NaN  NaN
3  d    d  NaN
4  e  NaN  NaN
5  f    f  NaN
6  g  NaN    g
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few args in `pd.merge` that you can use for this purpose: `left_on`, `right_on` and `how`.

`left_on` allows you to specify which column in the left dataframe you would like to pandas to join on.

`right_on` is similar to `left_on` but for right dataframe.

`how` allows you to specify which type of join you would like to. In this case you probably want to perform a left join.

Learn more on this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html

You can do something like this:

```
l1 = ["a", "b" , "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
l2 = ["a", "d", "f"]
l3 = ["b", "g"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'l1': l1})
df_l2 = pd.DataFrame({'l2': l2})
df_l3 = pd.DataFrame({'l3': l3})
df = pd.merge(df, df_l2, left_on='l1', right_on='l2', how='left') 
df = pd.merge(df, df_l3, left_on='l1', right_on='l3', how='left')
```

Output:

```
l1   l2   l3
0  a    a  NaN
1  b  NaN    b
2  c  NaN  NaN
3  d    d  NaN
4  e  NaN  NaN
5  f    f  NaN
6  g  NaN    g
```